# Nested arrays with Php and SQL

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I really need your help.

I know how to create with PHP and SQL a json array.

I am creating mine

But I need to create a nested one, and I kinda got lost there.

I saw many other questions similar to this one but still cant get it.

I want my array to looks like this one:

```
"names": {
   "name_id": {
       "firstname": "john",
       "lastname": "doe",
       "age": 18,
       "menu": {
           "dinner": {
               "dinner1": "119",
               "dinner2": "229",
               "dinner3": "379",
               "dinner4": "559"
           }
        },
        "deep_link_url": "http:\/\/testurl.com\/?name_id=42422&ref=CC",
        "bonus_offers": "some_bonus"
   },
```

Here is my code:

```
$return_arr = array();

$sql = "sp_getdata";
$fetch = sqlsrv_query($connection,$sql); 
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($fetch)) {
   $row_array['name_id'] = $row['name_id'];
   $row_array['firstname'] = $row['firstname'];
   $row_array['lastname'] = $row['lastname'];
   $row_array['age'] = $row['age'];
   $row_array['dinner1'] = $row['dinner1'];
   $row_array['dinner2'] = $row['dinner2'];
   $row_array['dinner3'] = $row['dinner3'];
   $row_array['dinner4'] = $row['dinner14'];
   $row_array['deep_link_url'] = url().'/name_id='.$name_id;
   $row_array['bonus_offers'] = $row['bonus_offer'];

   array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

I get everything into just one. Whats the way to make them nested?

Sorry if my question is not clear enough for someone but that's how I am imagine that in my head. Please someone explain and help!

Comment: your `$row_array` should be multidimensional array

Comment: @geeth So should I just change ti to "$row_array['menu']['dinner']['dinner1']" or  nothing like that?

Comment: @geeth if not can you please let me know how?

Comment: What about RTFM?
 http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php sec 14

Comment: @AlivetoDie why you dont? It does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it like below:-

```
$return_arr = array();

$sql = "sp_getdata";
$fetch = sqlsrv_query($connection,$sql); 
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($fetch)) {
   $row_array['name_id'] = $row['name_id'];
   $row_array['firstname'] = $row['firstname'];
   $row_array['lastname'] = $row['lastname'];
   $row_array['age'] = $row['age'];
   $row_array['menu']['dinner']['dinner1'] = $row['dinner1']; //check change
   $row_array['menu']['dinner']['dinner2'] = $row['dinner2']; //check change
   $row_array['menu']['dinner']['dinner3'] = $row['dinner3']; //check change
   $row_array['menu']['dinner']['dinner4'] = $row['dinner14']; //check change
   $row_array['deep_link_url'] = url().'/name_id='.$name_id;
   $row_array['bonus_offers'] = $row['bonus_offer'];

   $return_arr["names"][] = ["name_id"=>$row_array]; // instead of push assign directly
}

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

***A demo output:-*** https://eval.in/896214

Comment: Is not 100% what I want to display but thanks for give me the idea of how to solve it. Really appreciate it. Just have to make a bit changes but that make all this json array much clearer.. Thanks

Comment: @Maria  glad to help you :):)